# How to hydrate a WinJS.Class

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am serializing and storing an object that was created from a WinJS.Class like this:

```
var myClass = WinJS.Class.define(...);
var myObject = new myClass();
var serialized = JSON.stringify(myObject);
//store the object
```

And later I'm pulling the object out of storage and I want to deserialize it and cast it as a `myClass`. Is that possible with WinJS out of the box or do I need to create a constructor for my class that is capable of taking an object that can turn it into a new object?

I haven't broken into TypeScript yet, and I think that would help out in this situation, but until then I'm wondering how to do it with plain JavaScript/WinJS.

Comment: Neither WinJS, nor typescript will help here. The JSONing process will gut the functions & prototype chain from the instance. You need to reconstruct them the other side by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle this, and none are particularly special to WinJS. Simply put: JSON serialization only serializes and deserializes the obje values, not its methods, prototype, or other type information.

**Option 1: Copy values to new instance of your class**
This is usually best accomplished by having your constructor take the deserialized object as a parameter and copying the data to the new instance.

There are a variety of variations of this. Using the object constructor is generally the best for performance, as this typically enables the JS engine to apply the greater number of optimizations to the object.

WinJS.UI.setOptions can be helpful here, or you can just copy the data using a simple loop like this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(source);
for (var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    destination[key] = source[key];
}
```

**Option 2: Setting __proto__**
Warning: This can have significantly adverse performance effects, so it's not appropriate in some situations. But occasionally it can be handy.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(myObject, myClass.prototype);
```

Note that setPrototypeOf is relatively new. It's there on Win8.1 for web apps (which I'm guessing this is about) and in IE 11, but not available in Safari, for example. On older browsers/ Safari, assigning to **proto** is the equivalent (but if available, setPrototypeOf is better).

This will attach methods from myClass to the object, but in addition to the negative performance effects, also does not run your constructor on the object - so it still may not be in exactly the same state as the object you originally serialized.

**Other helpful thing: JSON "revivers"**
JSON.parse takes an optional second parameter, called a "reviver". This lets you provide a function that gets the opportunity to transform each node of the JSON being deserialized. This can be useful for rehydrating serialized dates into JavaScript Date objects, for example. It also gets the opportunity to transform the top-most object, which could be useful in some cases to turn the deserialized object into the "class" you want.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a dynamic language so I think you dont need to cast the deserialized object, just treat it as myClass type and that's it. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the 'Options' constructor pattern, where the option value is the deserialized object:

```
// MovieModel Constructor
// ----------------------
function MovieModel(options) {
    this._titleValue = options.title || "Sample Title";
}
```

Where the movie methods closure is something like this:

```
// MovieModel Methods
// ------------------
var movieModelMethods = {
    title: {
        get: function () {
            return this._titleValue;
        },
        set: function (val) {
            this._titleValue = val;
            this.dispatchEvent("title");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: For this pattern, WinJS provides the setOptions helper, which is basically a simple property copying mechanism to copy the properties from "options" to "this" (in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Since WinJS class define can only specify one constructor function (as far as I understand it), you may use the static members to define a factory function that will take the serialized data as a parameter. This factory methdod will actually create a new instance and will set the values one by one and return the new object.

It as some advantages like the fact that you can actually manage the data structure changes over the time you enhance the app... 
The drawback is that you cannot write new MySuperClass() all the time...

```
...
// let's suppose we already called JSON.parse(data);
create: function(serializedData) {
    var newObj = new MySuperClass();
    newObj.name = serializedData.name || "";
    newObj.color = serializedData.color || "";
    return newObj;
}
```

Then you will call somewhere else in the app :

```
var myInstance = MySuperClass.create(serializedDataFromfile);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should just be able to call JSON.parse after pulling it out of local storage:

var myObject2;
myObject2 = JSON.parse(localStorage["mySeriazliedObject"];

Comment: As Dominic points out above, this will not give you any functions, only properties.